# Jade HTML attribute called "attribute"

Tags: html, pug, polymer

Working with Polymer Project markup, the `<element>` and `<polymer-element>` tags take an attribute called `attributes` to publish things in the custom element [(1)](http://www.polymer-project.org/polymer.html#published-properties).

This causes problems in jade, since since [#617](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/pull/617) `attributes` as an attribute name is treated specially. Is there a workaround for this in Jade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a '\' before the attributes-attribute, like so

```
polymer-element(\attributes='foo bar')
```

It was just a guess, but it worked. Can't find any reference in the documentation on this.

So consider it as a work around.

Answer (score 2):

After the recent update to jade (v1.0.0 and greater) `attributes` is no longer special cased.  As such you can just write:

```
polymer-element(attributes='foo bar')
```

results in:

```
<polymer-element attributes="foo bar"></polymer-element>
```

If you want to try it out in your browser you can do so at: http://jade-lang.com/demo/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps in your particular situation, but note that you can use an object property called `publish` in your prototype in place of the `attributes` attribute on the `<polymer-element>`.

E.g.

```
<polymer-element attributes='foo bar'...>...
```

is equivalent to

```
<polymer-element...>...
  <script>
    Polymer(..., {
      publish: {
        foo: null,
        bar: null
      }
    }
```

That way you should be able, at least, to write your own elements without bumping into Jade syntax.

Comment: Yes, this is the workaround I'm currently using. Given the notes in Polymer about the preferred "attributes" syntax, and my own aesthetic preferences, I'd prefer the markup-based solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just to keep this answer up-to-date, `attributes` is no more reserved in jade :).